# Where does SQL Server 2005 keep the .mdf files?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, mdf

I'm upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to 2008.  I've detached the database I need, but can't find it on the file system.

Where does a default installation of SQL Server 2005 store these?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use management studio to look at the properties>files of any database - that will show the files and their growth settings.

Answer (score 13):

try this, run this query

```
use model
go
SELECT physical_name FROM sys.database_files
```

in my case on my laptop it is in this folder

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\

Answer (score 6):

By default, in `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\`

Comment: not always true, especially not on a server, for example on my server Log files are on the L drive and data files on the U and V drives..it is determined by the model database

Comment: @SQLMenace: He's asking about a _default_ installation

Comment: I see, it also depends what you mean by default, our default is L for logs, M for system, T for tempdb and rest of userDB

Comment: @SQLMenace: But that's not a default _installation_.

Answer (score 5):

The default locations for SQL Server 2005 are:

- \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\ for the Database Engine
- \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\OLAP\ for Analysis Services
- \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\RS\ for Reporting Services

See [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143547%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for more details.

Sometimes you can't look at the properties if one of the systems files is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

you can always go to **SQL Server Management Studio** and right click on the **database**, than select **proprieties**, than go on the angle **Files**, you will see two files displayed in a table on is **MDF** file and **Log** file , check the **path** ! go to that folder, your database is the **MDF file** !

PS : to be able to copy i think you have to terminate the **SqlServer** Processes, that's a little dirty way isn't, but it's fast and i use it, works for me !

Answer (score 1):

Go to C Drive --> Program  Files --> Microsoft SQL Server --> MSSQLXX --> MSSQL -- > DATA

The Data Folder has mdf and log files both.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a database export from management studio so there aren't any compatibility issues.